# Using a with clause in Neo4jClient cypher fluent queries

Tags: neo4jclient

I'm trying to write a cypher query with a [WITH clause](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-with.html) using Neo4JClient. However, I can't see a With operation anywhere in any of the ICypherFluentQuery namespaces.

Does Neo4JClient support with clauses? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does, from build 1.0.0.500.

Comment: I thought I had Neo4JClient up to date, but I was sure .With wasn't there before. How strange.

Comment: We've released 507 builds to NuGet now. It moves pretty quickly, often with multiple releases in a single day. :)